# CreateObject Layer invalid data source

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am trying to finalize some code for a class that I am taking and had to move it to another location and I renewed the paths. After that things started to go crazy. I have copied/ paste all of the new directories and made sure that the shapefile still works (which it does) and is still located in the file folder. the error is on line 47 :layer = mapping.Layer(r"C:\Workspace\GIST315\Project_folder\New File Geodatabase.gdb\Active_Rigs"). below is the error.

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'layer'
>>>
```

---

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder"
from arcpy import da #this will allow access to the data access module
from arcpy import mapping # Mapping Module
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Open a map document (shell document)
Rig_mxd = mapping.MapDocument("C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/mxd files/Rig Activity.mxd")
AP_mxd = mapping.MapDocument("C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/mxd files/Permitted Activity.mxd")


#Setting Dataframes in order of MXD. Only one frame per MXD.
first_df = mapping.ListDataFrames(Rig_mxd)[0]
second_df = mapping.ListDataFrames(AP_mxd)[0]
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Projection data procresses

#file output for Project active Rigs
file_output1 = "C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/Shapefiles/rig_exampleRigsDIShape.shp"
file_output2 = "C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Active_Rigs"


for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
        dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)

        if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
            print('skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: ' + file_output1)
        else:
            # Determine the new output feature class path and name
            outfc = os.path.join(file_output2, file_output1)

            # Set output coordinate system
            outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1927 StatePlane Texas Central FIPS 4203')

            # run project tool
            arcpy.Project_management(file_output1, file_output2, outCS)

            # check messages
            print(arcpy.GetMessages())

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#This is added to assure that rig symbology will always be on top
#Layers to be added to the data frame

layer = mapping.Layer("C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Active_Rigs")
# Change the name of the layer before adding
layer.name = "Rigs Locations"
# Add the layer at the top of the data frame
mapping.AddLayer(first_df,layer,"TOP")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#setting symbology

sym_layer = mapping.Layer("C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/sourceLayer/Rigs Locations.lyr")
layer_Rigs = mapping.ListLayers(Rig_mxd,"Rigs*",first_df)[0]
mapping.UpdateLayer(first_df,layer_Rigs,sym_layer,"TRUE")

Rig_mxd.saveACopy("C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/mxd files/Rig Activity_FINAL.mxd")

# Export Rig map to PDF
pdf_file = "C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/PDF exports/Rig Activity Map"
mapping.ExportToPDF(Rig_mxd,pdf_file,resolution=300)
```

Comment: You need to use a .lyr file to create a layer object with arcpy.mapping.Layer https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s30000001s000000/ as a layer file contains not just the link to the data but definition queries, FID sets, symbology etc. Therefore with the line *layer = mapping.Layer("C:/Workspace/GIST315/Project_folder/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Active_Rigs")* you're trying to create a layer from a feature class, which is not correct, to do this use arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000

Comment: interesting. I will have to give this a try in the morning. I tried this out before prior and it was working. I am new to this, but I will definitely use this method for now on.

Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I think giving a feature class is perfectly OK in ArcGIS Desktop. I have been using it all the time and complained about why it was removed from arcpy in ArcGIS Pro. Cross-platform-usability-wise, MakeFeatureLayer_management is better, though!

Comment: @fatih_dur I've hit this same problem many times in ArcGIS Desktop where a feature class has been provided where a layer is needed.. feature classes don't support operations like *select by attributes* but work just fine in operations like *buffer*, in short sometimes you'd get away with it but not all the time.